# copy and paste data from multiple worksheets with exception

Tags: excel, vba

Hello im new to VBA and I am using it for excel. I want to make the copy and paste the data from all of the worksheets except from one sheet, how do i do it for? How do i make the data to be pasted without overwriting each other and have the next data to be pasted in the next column?

I tried this code, the values just overwrites each other, making only the value of the last worksheet to be pasted at the end, and what should i add to make the exception for sheet2

```
Public Sub DoToAll()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In Worksheets
    
    ws.Range("A3:A300").Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
        
     Next

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To omit one worksheet, just check the name inside the loop.

To ensure that you don't overwrite the data in the destination cell and end up with only one row, ensure that you move to the next row. There are many ways to do so, in the following example I use a Range variable (`destRange`) and set it to the next row after a copy using the `Offset`-function.

```
Sub DoToAll()
    Const destSheetName = "Sheet2"
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim destRange As Range
    Set destRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(destSheetName).Range("E1")
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> destSheetName Then
            ws.Range("A3:A300").Copy
            destRange.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
            ' Goto Next row
            Set destRange = destRange.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works, but I have another questions, how can i update the code if i want the exceptions to be on the first  5 worksheets and when I cange the range of the data of A3:A300 to O3:O300, the values are 0 even though there are values in the worksheets. How do I solve this? Thank you